# Azure.Data.Tables doesn't honour IgnorePropertyAttribute

Tags: azure-table-storage, azure-sdk-.net

When using Azure.Data.Tables to work with Azure Table Storage in C#/F#, I am creating my custom entity types by implementing ITableEntity.

My class has additional properties which I don't want to save in the Azure Table.

It seems that the attribute IgnorePropertyAttribute should be used to decorate the properties to ignore.

However this attribute is in a different package Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table and it's not honoured by the latest version of Azure.Data.Tables 12.3.0.

How do I make the Table API in Azure.Data.Tables 12.3.0 ignore some of the property in my entity class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the information provided on this [`GitHub issue`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/19782), you will need to use `IgnoreDataMember` attribute instead of `IgnoreProperty` attribute if you do not want certain members of your entity to be saved in the database.